# How do I make a shell script return desired error code?

Tags: bash

I am writing some tests that requires the calling program to give different error codes 
e.g., test script is like

cpu_test.sh

```
stress --cpu "$cpus" --timeout 30000 --verbose >> "$data"
[ $? -ne 0 ] && pass="fail" && echo "ERROR: CPU stress test has failed"
```

Now, I can't wait for 30000 seconds in my unit test. Hence I would like to to set the path to a fake 'stress' binary that would just return an error code:

```
$cat stress 
#!/bin/bash
exit 1
```

but echo $? returns '0' instead of 1 hence I am never able to test the negative test cases.

A C solution would be :
cat fio.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
return 1;
}
```

How do I make a shell script return the desired error code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you're testing the condition. First test the most simple thing:

```
$ cat stress
#!/bin/bash
exit 1

$ ./stress
$ echo $?
1
```

Are you sure you didn't mean:

```
[ $? -ne 0 ] && [ "$pass" == "fail" ] && echo "ERROR: CPU stress test has failed"
```